# Safari selection color on macOS is blue on empty spaces

Tags: css, safari, selection, line-breaks

Observe the two screenshots below, the first in Chrome and the second in Safari. Both browsers latest version as of date of question (Jan 2023).

[image]

[image]

The page background is the dark grey observed in Chrome. When CMD+A (select ALL) is pressed, the selection colour (yellow) should be applied as shown in Chrome. However, in Safari, two interesting observations can be seen:

1. Safari applies selection to blank space outside the text container (width).
2. Safari uses the native blue selection colour on `<br />` elements.

How can the blue selection be removed, and how can selection be contained within text width?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for certain without seeing your actual code, but based on the issues I had to solve today, my best guess would be:

1. For this issue you can apply any type of null transform to the parent container, for example `transform: translateY(0);`.
2. For this one you can set the offending element to `display: block;` or `display: flex;`. If you're dealing with a button or similar element that you don't want to go full width, you can set it to `max-width: max-content;`.

Hope that's helpful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  br::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
/* Remove the text shadow */
::selection {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).